# @EnableJpaRepositories is not detecting or @Autowired of Repository is not detected anywhere in spring-boot application

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have referred many stackoverflow questions similar to this. I have tried all the solutions provided and the suggestions. But keeps giving the error due to non-detection of @Autowired of Repository class irrespective of its definition in @EnableJpaRepositories in the Boot application file. I have tried using

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.example.repository") as well in the Boot application class. 
Nothing seems to resolve the error. 

Desperately seeking help from anyone who can find out what am I doing wrong. Please help me out. I have been trying to find on the internet and tried on my own. But still no luck and I have not been patient for the past two days because of this.

I want to resolve this and get ready to get a job using spring-boot-starter-data-jpa in their project. So please help.

===============================================================================

    enter code here

folder structure
src->main->java->com
  - ApplicationDataSource.java
src->main->java->com->example->controller
  - H2Controller.java
src->main->java->com->example->service
  - H2Service.java
src->main->java->com->example->repository
  - H2Repository.java
-------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2sample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>h2sample</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

---------------------------------------------------

    

package com;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.example.repository.H2Repository;
import com.example.repository.City;


/*
 * @Configuration
 * 
 * @EnableAutoConfiguration
 * 
 * @ComponentScan("com.example.h2sample")
 */

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= {"com.example.controller","com.example.service"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.repository")
public class H2sampleApplication {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(H2sampleApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    

}
--------------------




package com.example.controller;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.example.service.H2Service;

@RestController
public class H2Controller {
    
    
    @Autowired
    private H2Service h2service;
        
    @GetMapping(value="/testh2")
    public String testh2() {
        
        return "Hi Test "+h2service.getH2Service();
    }

}

-------------------------------------------




package com.example.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import com.example.repository.H2Repository;
import com.example.repository.City;




@Service
public class H2Service {
    
    
    
     @Autowired
     private H2Repository<City> h2repository;
        
    
    public String getH2Service() {
        
        System.out.println(h2repository.findAll());
        return " from Service";
    }
}

--------------------------------------
package com.example.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.util.List;


public interface H2Repository<City> extends CrudRepository<City, Long> {
    
    public List<City> findAll();

}
-----------------------------------------





package com.example.repository;

import java.util.Objects;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "CITY")
public class City {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private int population;

    public Long getId() {

        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {

        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {

        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPopulation() {

        return population;
    }

    public void setPopulation(int population) {

        this.population = population;
    }
    
}

===================================================================

server.servlet.context-path=/h2
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./test-db
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true



Error
----

H2Sample\h2sample\target\classes started by Sethu in H:\H2Sample\h2sample)
2020-07-28 11:39:01.955  INFO 14236 --- [           main] com.H2sampleApplication                  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-07-28 11:39:02.453  INFO 14236 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-07-28 11:39:02.511  INFO 14236 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 46ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-07-28 11:39:03.610  INFO 14236 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-07-28 11:39:03.624  INFO 14236 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-07-28 11:39:03.624  INFO 14236 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.37]
2020-07-28 11:39:03.754  INFO 14236 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/h2]     : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-07-28 11:39:03.755  INFO 14236 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1736 ms
2020-07-28 11:39:03.922  INFO 14236 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-07-28 11:39:04.047  INFO 14236 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-07-28 11:39:05.024  INFO 14236 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-07-28 11:39:05.072  INFO 14236 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.18.Final
2020-07-28 11:39:05.309  INFO 14236 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-07-28 11:39:05.414  INFO 14236 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
Hibernate: drop table if exists city CASCADE
Hibernate: create table city (id bigint not null, name varchar(255), population integer not null, primary key (id))
2020-07-28 11:39:05.970  INFO 14236 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-07-28 11:39:05.980  INFO 14236 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-07-28 11:39:06.135  WARN 14236 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'h2Controller': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'h2service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'h2Service': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'h2repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'h2Repository' defined in com.example.repository.H2Repository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on H2sampleApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object
2020-07-28 11:39:06.136  INFO 14236 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-07-28 11:39:06.141  INFO 14236 --- [           main] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
Hibernate: drop table if exists city CASCADE
2020-07-28 11:39:06.150  INFO 14236 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-07-28 11:39:06.188  INFO 14236 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2020-07-28 11:39:06.194  INFO 14236 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-07-28 11:39:06.223  INFO 14236 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-07-28 11:39:06.255 ERROR 14236 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'h2Controller': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'h2service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'h2Service': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'h2repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'h2Repository' defined in com.example.repository.H2Repository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on H2sampleApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at com.H2sampleApplication.main(H2sampleApplication.java:28) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'h2Service': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'h2repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'h2Repository' defined in com.example.repository.H2Repository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on H2sampleApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'h2Repository' defined in com.example.repository.H2Repository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on H2sampleApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:582) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.18.Final.jar:5.4.18.Final]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:75) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:229) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:179) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:162) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:72) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:309) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:212) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        ... 43 common frames omitted

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  9.079 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-07-28T11:39:06+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project h2sample: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I need help desperately as I need to join an Organization in which Spring-boot-data-jpa is  being used in their project. I appreciate help urgently.

Comment: This looks like a bug. Is there any reference with springboot project?

Answer (score 8):

Do not need the component scan if you have your main class at the top of the structure, also not need

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.example.repository") as well in the Boot application class.
```

only need
@SpringBootApplication in your main class.

HERE NOT FOLLOWING DEFAULT STRUCTURE OF SPRING

use the
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example"})

try this following code:

```
@SpringBootApplication   
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"<base package name>"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="<repository package name>")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EntityScan(basePackages="<entity package name>")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works fine now and the components are mapped properly. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 3):

In your Service class, replace below

```
 @Autowired
 private H2Repository<City> h2repository;
```

with

```
 @Autowired
 private H2Repository h2repository;
```

And also your repository interface, replace below

```
 public interface H2Repository<City> extends CrudRepository<City, Long>
```

with

```
 public interface H2Repository extends CrudRepository<City, Long>
```

Comment: I tried it already. But still getting the same error. I am tired of this error. If you have any other suggestions please share. Thanks

Comment: Try adding @Repository to the repository interface

Comment: Sorry, about my previous comment. It really works fine after I removed the generics <City> as directed by you. Thank you sooooooo much. God be with you. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

This may also be a consequence of incorrect placement of the Entity class. Look in which folder the other Entity classes are located.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I could solve this issue by selecting the right java version, dependencies in pom.xml, application.properties and made sure the SQL server is running.