# Spring JPA H2: "Error creating bean with name 'userInfoRepository'"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, h2

I got a spring-boot application which runs just fine on my machine. When I deploy the .war to a webserver, I run into this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userInfoRepository' defined in myproject.repository.UserInfoRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class entities.UserInfo
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
```

however, I have no "UserInfoRepository" or "UserInfo" class defined anywhere in my project. So I do not know what to make of this error.

I use JpaRepositories and a local H2 DB. The DB is created on startup correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@EnableJpaRepositories is not detecting or @Autowired of Repository is not detected anywhere in spring-boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63128209/enablejparepositories-is-not-detecting-or-autowired-of-repository-is-not-detec)

Comment: I tried but this but got the same error. Please note: Autowiring and the whole application works fine on my machine. I only get the error after deploying the .war to a webserver